# Linux awk command doesn't print integers correctly?

Tags: linux, command

Can someone explain why this command doesn't print out a list of PID without the newline?
I want output like:

```
1234 5678 123 456
```

I tried all these, and none of them work

```
ps -eww --no-headers -o pid,args | grep 'usr' | awk '{ printf "%d ", $1 }'
ps -eww --no-headers -o pid,args | grep 'usr' | awk '{ printf "%s ", $1 }'
ps -eww --no-headers -o pid,args | grep 'usr' | awk '{ print $1 }' | tr '\n' ''
ps -eww --no-headers -o pid,args | grep 'usr' | awk '{ print $1 }' | tr -d '\n'
```

I just found out bash works fine, but not zsh in my case

Comment: What OS are you using?  OSx, Linux, etc ?   On my OSX mnt lion, it works if i remove --no-headers.

Comment: The first two should work, except the output not having a final newline can have some funny interaction with your shell prompt. What if you pipe it into `less` or `more`? What's exactly the problem as you see it?

Comment: I have redhat zsh. hmm, I just found out that bash works, but not zsh, can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Try `awk '{ printf "%d ", $1 } END { print ""}'`

Comment: Anton, that works in my zsh. Do you know the reason?

Comment: @user926958 I've found the reason: it's a **feature** of `zsh`. See my answer for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`zsh` has a *feature* of letting the user know that the last output line was partial (i.e. there were no final newline). For more details on this you can look up `PROMPT_CR`, `PROMPT_SP` and `PROMPT_EOL_MARK` in [`man zshoptions`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/zshoptions).

You can add `PROMPT_EOL_MARK=''` to your `~/.zshrc` to make the partial line indicator empty, but I would advise against it: now we know that it's just a feature, and sometimes we can notice a problem with our data if we leave it enabled. On a reasonably powerful terminal, the percent sign (the default when `PROMPT_EOL_MARK` is unset) is output **bold** and inverted, so it can't be confused with a piece of actual output.

Your command's output is a list of pids exactly as you desired. Adding a final newline makes it also *look* right with `zsh`:

```
ps -eww --no-headers -o pid,args | awk '/usr/ { printf "%d ", $1 } END {print""}'
```

(using also another answer's idea of getting rid of `grep` using the power of `awk`).

Answer (score 1):

It does for me like this:

```
ps -eww --no-headers -o pid,args | awk '/usr/{printf "%d ",$1}'
```

I.e. `awk` can search for strings matching regular expressions, so you don't really need `grep` when using `awk`.